Automatic merging of users from LDAP and Keycloak into Youtrack
Initially, the LDAP Auth Module was used for authorization.
Now we are connecting to Youtrack Keycloak.
Accordingly, it is necessary that users logging in through Keycloak be the same users as those received from LDAP.
To do this, I have configured the user attributes received in the Youtrack fields from Keycloak to match those from LDAP. LDAP AND KEYCLOAK CONFIGS
However, with such settings, when the "User creation" parameter is disabled, authorization does not occur: hub-auth-login-failed: Log in failed
If you enable this parameter, the newly created user will have the received attribute in the "username" field, but with the addition of randomly generated characters
some random characters
Tell me if there is a way to connect these two modules somehow. Or, for example, set up an automatic merge of accounts?

YouTrack only tries to match a Keycloak user to an existing user if the user details contain the verified email data. So, you need to also configure mapping for the "Email verification state" field. Usually, mapping it to email_verified works.
Once you do this, YouTrack will try to match the Keycloak user to some existing user by email, so make sure that there will be a match. You might need to change preferred_username to email for this to work.
Before trying this out, delete the newly created user and switch "User creation" back to "Disabled".
